# Why does setting the body's background-image's background-position to center move the image up?

Tags: html, css

With centered background image:

```css
/*backgrounds and colors*/

body {
  background-color: rgb(10, 20, 51);
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6a/29/28/6a2928106b907101787cd87f6613bdec.gif");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Without centered background image:

```css
/*backgrounds and colors*/

body {
  background-color: rgb(10, 20, 51);
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6a/29/28/6a2928106b907101787cd87f6613bdec.gif");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Why did the image move up when I set the background-position to center?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you havn't set the width and height of the container. Providing `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh` with `background-position: center` will centrally position the image.

```css
/*backgrounds and colors*/

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(10, 20, 51);
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6a/29/28/6a2928106b907101787cd87f6613bdec.gif");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how come the entire viewport is painted blue when the height is not set?